# JavaScript: Slice an array into three (roughly) equal arrays

Tags: javascript

How do I slice an array like this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8];
```

into thirds (ie. three arrays, like this):

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8]
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
var first = a.slice(0, Math.ceil(a.length / 3));
var seconds = ???
var third = ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, though it can be cleaned up:

```
var m, n;
var first, second, third;    

m = Math.ceil(a.length / 3);
n = Math.ceil(2 * a.length / 3);

first = a.slice(0, m);
second = a.slice(m, n);
third = a.slice(n, a.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get the length. Nice and simple: `a.length`

Next, divide by three and round *up*. This will be the size of your pieces.

Finally, use `a.slice()` with appropriate arguments to get the resulting arrays.

Write some code using the above algorithm, and let us know if you have any more specific problems :)