# chunking javascript array range to n equal parts?

Tags: javascript

How to divide this ans array into n equal parts?
if 1-100 is the provided input, i want the output to be in chunks of 10, displayed in separate lines.

```
function range(start, end) {
   var ans = [];
   for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    ans.push(i);
   }
   return ans;
}
```

Comment: possible duplication of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595337/javascript-slice-an-array-into-three-roughly-equal-arrays?noredirect=1&lq=1
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188548/splitting-a-js-array-into-n-arrays

Comment: can you provide input and expected output array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function ( n ) {
      if ( !this.length ) {
          return [];
      }
      return [this.slice(0, n)].concat(this.slice(n).chunk(n));
    };
```

And then:

```
const splittendAns = ans.chunk(20);
```

With the last line you divide the array in chunks of length `20`.

---

Here an example as requested:

```
// Suppose I have this array
// I want to split this array in 5 length arrays
const array = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
];

Array.prototype.chunk = function ( n ) {
    if ( !this.length ) {
        return [];
    }
    return [this.slice(0, n)].concat(this.slice(n).chunk(n));
};

const splittedArray = array.chunk(5);

console.log(array);
console.log('-----');
console.log(splittedArray);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
-----
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ], [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ] ]
```

Comment: @LibinVarghese added an example.

Comment: can i add different colors to the each array chunk?

Comment: @LibinVarghesewhat do you mean with different colors? Do you want to split an array of strings? In that case you can to the same...